# Getting Error loading Could not load file or assembly error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, specflow, testcomplete

When I click on build Solution on  my project and when I wanted to view Test name in Test step I got 
Error loading

> F:\Manas\CMCVTestAutomation\Barclays.CMCV.TestAutomation\Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories\bin\Debug\Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories.dll:
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///F:\Manas\CMCVTestAutomation\Barclays.CMCV.TestAutomation\Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories\bin\Debug\Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131515) error.

please let me know the solution of this error

Comment: Did you check if the mentioned file existed?

Comment: yes I checked that ..that file existed in that folder..

Answer (score 0):

This means your project cannot compile. Check for compilation errors and fix them.

Also, under your solution explorer, expand the project's references and check if any is having problem loading.

Is the "Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories" project, part of your solution? It seems that it has dependencies that are missing. Try to spot them. If it is not part of the solution, you will have to contact the creator of it and discuss the dependencies.

Comment: when I compile that it gives me no errors.This error shows only when i Open test view .

Comment: Try to browse to the file it mentions and see if you have the specific file at this path. And, again, have you checked the references?

Comment: ya I checked that file existed in that folder

Comment: See last paragraph of my updated answer, you have to check the dependencies of the specific dll as well.

Comment: Yes ,"Barclays.CMCV.Collateral.Stories"is part of my project solution.Problem is that same code and same set up is working fine on different machine with same configuration ,But in my machine I was facing this issue.

Comment: You never answered if you have checked the references of this specific project on your machine... The fact that it works on another machine might be due to Global assemblies that the other has and you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a DLL that you have downloaded from the internet which is a dependency? Could it be that it is blocked?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753979/visual-studio-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-erro)