# Could not load file or assembly in Release mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-reference

I have  a asp.net project in vs 2012. before adding  a web reference every thing is OK. but when I add web reference again every things is OK in **Debug mode**. but in **Release mode** I have this error.

Could not load file or assembly 'x.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

when I remove web references it will be OK.
but dlls exist in the address. how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753979/visual-studio-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-erro

Comment: @Neptune   no it is not the same because I have checked this links and as you can see my code is Ok when I remove web reference

Comment: Have you tried the solution there and it didn't work? or you just think you have a different issue? Because I think the fact removing the reference solves it doesn't necessarily make different from that question.

Comment: @Neptune. yes I 've tried several times  and I am sure when i remove references every thing is fine.